# Detach Disk from GCE VM to mount and edit SSH

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

i am trying to detach disk on temp instance so i can mount and edit ssh_config but when i am using `gcloud compute instances detach-disk INSTANCE --disk mydisk` it shows

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.detach-disk) There was a problem fetching the resource:
 - Insufficient Permission
```

any suggestion? i'm new to google Cloud

Answer (score 2):

You need to authorize your account before you can use your gcloud command. You can run the following command to authorize.

```
$ gcloud auth login
```